# NSXMLParser for xml! why is it so hard to use? is there an easy way?

Tags: cocoa, nsxmlparser, xmldocument

For the last few hours I have tired to get my head around using NSXMLParser.

I understand parts of how it works.

WHY Oh WHY! is this so hard? Is there an easy way to do it, like just name the tag and get the contents?

Oh how I miss XmlDocument object from .Net.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: You should post what you've tried and then maybe we could help you make it work.  Are you having issues with the object's interface, or objective-C itself? If you just want to rant, try craigslist.

Comment: Question was what other options do I have to parse a kml file.

Comment: +1 for the "rant" comment. Better to ask a real question here than simply to vaguely bemoan that something is "hard."

Comment: Sorry about the rant there was a question in there :) which was answered :P

Comment: Hey Morry, here's a class that provides a one-line method for parsing an XML file: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead? With it you can do the kind of things you want using xpaths. Check out the docs or this sample code : http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/iPad/index.html#samplecode/XMLBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008875

Comment: Links are broken.